# "Watched Tags" as links on the top of each page

Tags: feature-request, support

I have about 10 tags in my "Watched Tags". Once I go to a particular tag, there is no way to jump to another tag unless I go back to "Watched Tags" and click on the other tag I am interested in. This is frustrating if I want to move around tags. It would be nice is to have them as links on the top of the page (under the banner).